# Can't open drive after writing bootsector

Tags: assembly, boot, x86-16

I write my assembly program to boot sector of my USB drive, then I am not able to open it. I mean when I go to my computer and click in USB icon, windows ask me to format it.

possibly what mistake I am doing? I am modifying only first sector of my drive. it should not affect file system. am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a USB drive, I think that's referred to as the VBR (Volume Boot Record).

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_Boot_Record):

> In file systems such as FAT12 (except for in DOS 1.x), FAT16, FAT32,
>   HPFS and NTFS, **the VBR also contains a BIOS parameter block (BPB) that
>   specifies the location and layout of the principal on-disc data
>   structures for the file system**.

So if you overwrite the VBR, then Windows probably can't find the file system.

Answer (score 2):

You might have done any number of things wrong. Maybe you just *think* you only wrote the first sector, when you actually overwrote part of the file system. In addition, boot sectors contain information about the drive geometry, the file system type, etc. If you trash the boot sector, you make the disk unreadable by normal means.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but I'm pretty sure in most cases there is important information about partition layout in the boot sector, without which an OS will probably have trouble even finding the file systems.